# Regex (or other python option pref. pandas) to match all non digits BUT period, plus and minus (.,+,-)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I saw many similar questions but none solve this issue.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dummy'] = ['gg-21.534wgtr..eu678+ithn']
```

I would like to get,

```
-21.534..678+
```

I want to actually remove those characters, so my attempt,

```
df['dummy'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+','')

21534678
```

is not working.

regex would be my first choice, otherwise any pandas alternative, of just any python alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
df['dummy'] = df['dummy'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[^\d.+-]+', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cAPFW/1).

The pandas method is `Series.str.replace` to find and replace matches with another string (empty one, since you are removing matches).

The pattern you need is `[^\d.+-]+`, a *negated character class* that matches any char, 1 or more occurrences, other than a digit, `.`, `+` or `-`. Note the position of `-`, it must be at the start or end of the character class to be treated as a literal `-` symbol, or it will create a range.

Comment: I think this is the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to grasp your question but this give me your requested output from your example:

```
import re
reg_exp = re.compile("([0-9+\-.,]+)")

string = 'gg-21.534wgtr..eu678+ithn'
res = reg_exp.findall(string)
print(''.join(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this with python re

Explanation:

`\d+`   (any digits)

`|` (or)

`\.+` (any `.` of any length)

`|` (or)

`\+` (any single `+` >> add a `+` to mke it any length `\++`)

`|` (or)

`\-` (any single `-` >> add a `+` for any length `\--`)

```
import pandas as pd
import re
pattern = r'\d+|\.+|\+|\-'
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dummy'] = [''.join(re.findall(pattern, 'gg-21.534wgtr..eu678+ithn'))]

print(df)

         dummy
0  21.534..678+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no regex master but my first solution would be

> [^\d+-\.]